# Print 10 characters per line

Tags: java, methods

hello i have some trouble doing my coding on this question;

Write a method that prints characters using the following header:
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine)
This method prints the characters between ch1 and ch2 with the specified numbers per line. Write test program that prints ten characters per line from ‘l’ and ‘Z’.

can somebody show me the coding sample to solve my problem? thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask].  You need to show some effort in working on your problem.  If you are stuck on a specific issue, then please show some code, and elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Characters are encoded in ASCII. Each character has a unique decimal number representation. We can access these characters by their numbers, rather than the actual character.

For example, the character `'A'` has an ASCII code of 65. We don't really need to know the integer codes to use their respective character representations though. We can just typecast the integers into `char`s.

We can also use characters in simple arithmetic. Since `'A'` has ASCII code 65, then it makes sense for 65 + 1 = 66 to represent the character `'B'`. Indeed it does.

```
public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine) {
   if(ch1 <= 'Z' && ch2 >= 'a')
      return;

   int count = 0; //count number of characters on a line.
   char nextChar = ch1; //initialize our next character

   while(nextChar <= ch2) { //test case
      System.out.print(nextChar);
      count++; //once we print a character, increment our count

      if(count == numberPerLine) { //check if we reach our desired amount of characters
         System.out.println();
         count = 0; //once we print a new line, restart the count
      }

      nextChar = (char) (nextChar + 1); //get next character
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you @Tom! My choice of variable name (nextChar) was misleading because it was never actually getting the next character, but the ith character from `ch1`.

Comment: Well a problem with the is the difference between uppercase and lowercase letters....

Comment: I've added a small check in the beginning of the method. Thanks @ManOfPanda

Comment: thanks, but im using invoke method so the output didnt came out

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that seems to wok on my end.

```
public static String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static void printChars(char ch1, char ch2, int numberPerLine){
    int currentNumber = numberPerLine;

    int beginningIndex = alphabet.indexOf((ch1 + "").toLowerCase()) + 1;
    int endingIndex = alphabet.indexOf((ch2 + "").toLowerCase());

    for(int i = beginningIndex; i < endingIndex; i++){
        System.out.print(alphabet.charAt(i));
        if(currentNumber > 1){
            currentNumber --;
        }else{
            System.out.println("");
            currentNumber = numberPerLine;
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printChars('c', 'z', 2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me out, but i try to run it and the output didnt came out.

Comment: @hananihamdan H Did you use a main method and run arguments through it? I added that part to the code.

Comment: yes i did and ive tried so many ways and it didnt work very well

Comment: @hananihamdan What do you mean? What does it print? Works perfectly on my side...